# websphere - CWWKE0054E error unable to open file

Tags: java, command-line, websphere, server, websphere-liberty

i am trying run the websphere liberty profile server from the command line. I am following the steps told here : https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments/

I have created the server with the name server1.

But when the extraction completes and I try to start the server using the command : `server start server1`

the server throws an error : `CWWKE0054E: Unable to open file C:\wlp\wlp\usr\servers\server1\logs\C:\Users\Furquan\AppData\Local\Temp\\ihp_custom_batches.log.`. Now I know this cant be a valid path, but I dont know where and how to change it. Please help !!

Comment: You need to find where in your code you are referring to the `ihp_custom_batches.log`. As this is not Liberty file, but your application log file. As it looks like it probably is constructed in the form of incorrect relative path.

Comment: no I am not using this log file anywhere. What actually is happening is, I am trying to use liberty profile of WAS through command line, but when I try to start the server then it shows the error, none of my code is being run at this time. I am unable to resolve it , please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is related to the `LOG_FILE` environment variable that you have defined in your environment by some other program. To solve that, you have the following opions:

- Remove `LOG_FILE` env variable, if it is no longer needed by your system
- If you cant do that, override it via `server.env` file, that you can create in the `wlp\usr\servers\serverName` directory with the following content:

  ```
  LOG_FILE=console.log
  ```
- As last resort (this is not recommended, will make your installation NOT SUPPORTED and in certain installations might get overwritten by updates) - modify the `server.bat` command line script - in the script find the following section:

  ```
  if not defined LOG_FILE (
      set X_LOG_FILE=console.log
    ) else (
      set X_LOG_FILE=!LOG_FILE!
    )
  ```

And after the line `set X_LOG_FILE=!LOG_FILE!` just add another line that will override it with the default like this `set X_LOG_FILE=console.log`

In general, I'd recommend second solution (with the `server.env` file), as it is the most portable and will work in any environment.

Comment: I would not suggest modifying server.bat at all since IBM does not support modifications to files in the wlp/bin/ directory.  For more information about files that you should not change, see the Liberty profile externals support topic: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_profile_externals.html

Comment: @bkail I agree, that's why I recommended second option. I'll add a comment that it's not recommended and supported. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem for IBM Support Assistant V5. After I deleted %LOG_FILE% from Environment Variables, it worked.

Comment: If you didn't noticed, it is first bullet in the accepted answer ;)