# MobileFirst Platform : Can't launch mfp server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I actually try MobileFirst Platform Foundation for developer, I want to use it with the CLI but after installation when I want to start the server with: -mfp start
I have this message :

Initializing MobileFirst Console.
CWWKE0054E: Unable to open file C:\Users\bdupont.ibm\mobilefirst\7.1.0.00.20151012-1525\server\wlp\usr\servers\worklight\logs\C:\Users\MVENTU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ihp_custom_batches.log.
The server is listening on port 10080.
Server Directory: C:/Users/bdupont/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20151012-1525/server/
URL: http://localhost:10080/

If i try to see server status with mfp status it said that the worklight server is not running.

I tried to see log with mfp -d start but it doesn't seem to have issue.

If anyone have an idea?

Thank you.

---

Solution : [websphere - CWWKE0054E error unable to open file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955287/websphere-cwwke0054e-error-unable-to-open-file)

Look at Gas post, it was a problem of environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all the contents in mobilefirst/

In command prompt run

```
lsof -i :10800
kill -9 <port_number>
```

Then do `mfp start` again to restart the server